# How to solve for input received in cascading dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a complete beginner making a site for fun/skill development. I saw this code snippet online for cascading dropdowns, but when I run the below code, the form value for "First" comes through as the index number for the value I see in the dropdown (eg. Meals comes through as a 1).

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script>
    let data = [{
        item: 'Fruits',
        subitems: ['apple', 'banana', 'pineapple', 'watermelon']
      },
      {
        item: 'Meals',
        subitems: ['chicken', 'bacon', 'pork', 'beef']
      },
      {
        item: 'Animals',
        subitems: ['cat', 'rabbit', 'mouse', 'lion']
      },
      {
        item: 'Brands Laptops',
        subitems: ['Dell', 'HP', 'Apple', 'Sony'],
      },
    ];


    window.onload = function() {
      var itemSel = document.getElementById("first");
      var subitemSel = document.getElementById("seconda");
      var subitem2Sel = document.getElementById("secondb")

      for (var x in data) {
        itemSel.options[itemSel.options.length] = new Option(data[x].item, x);
      }
      itemSel.onchange = function() {
        //empty 
        subitemSel.length = 1;
        subitem2Sel.length = 1;
        //display correct values
        for (var y of data[this.value].subitems) {
          subitemSel.options[subitemSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
        }
        for (var z of data[this.value].subitems) {
          subitem2Sel.options[subitem2Sel.options.length] = new Option(z, z);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Cascading Dropdown Example</h1>

  <form name="form1" id="form1" action="/action_page.php">
    First:
    <select name="first" id="first">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select type</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Second A:
    <select name="seconda" id="seconda">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select first</option>
    </select>
    <br><br> Second B:
    <select name="secondb" id="secondb">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select first</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
```

I know how to alter the code to get the value of First to come through as the text, but that then messes up the cascading dropdowns. How can I get the form, upon hitting submit, to give me the text value from "First" and not the index number of whatever is selected?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Array's index starts from 0 so it makes sense that index of meals is 1

Comment: Thanks! Reading back, I wasn't clear on what my question was. How can I get the form, upon hitting submit, to give me the text value from "First" and not the index number of whatever is selected in that dropdown?